# Bootstrap Dropdown menu selection dependency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is couple things I am trying to with Bootstrap Dropdown Selection. I did look them up, but couldn't find anything useful

[MY DROPDOWN MENU](http://jsbin.com/voniva/edit?html,js,output)

Here is list of functions I like to make

1) After all dropdown menu selected, then you will be able click on submit. So submit needs to dependent all the dropdown selection

2) when dropdown "Select Year" is selected 2011, button text should show  "Year:2011" right now its showing just "2011"

[image]

3)After selection made, I would like to see text output under selection menu based on selection.
I found `alert()` example but that's not what I really wanted.

Such as **"Year:2011 Qtr: 1 State:Texas/Houston"**

I am newbie with javascript and bootstrap but I can go thru any documentation that will help me to accomplish all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code: http://jsbin.com/kelolifuda/1/edit?html,js,output
If I understand you correctly it should meet all your requirements.

Regards

Comment: Konrad This is awesome, but for state selection, when selected Texas>Houston. Can we make it display like "State:Texas/Houston" instead just Houston? I try to play with it but no luck. Thank you men!

Comment: Hello, I have made another update for you: http://jsbin.com/becazaqini/edit?html,js,output 
Just be aware that for this solution name of classes and data-attributes are very important, so be careful with changing them

Comment: Thank you Kondrad! I really appreciate for your help! I did implement to my real data and chart just fine :)